# upload image in server folder and save path in Sqlserver using entity framework mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am trying to save picture in folder and store path in Sqlserver 2008 using entity framework. I need register the user with picture. My code is saving all the data in database except picture and picture path.

```
My model is 

 {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    public partial class customer
    {

        [Display(Name="Username")]
        public string user_id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string first_name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string last_name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        public string address { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "City")]
        public string city { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "State")]
        public string state { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Zip")]
        public Nullable<int> zip { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        public string country { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Phone")]
        public string phone { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Picture")]
        public string picture { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Registration Date")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> reg_date { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public string status { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Keep me logged in")]
        public bool rememberme { get; set; }
     }
 }

My Controller is 

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(customer customer, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                        file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/image/") + file.FileName);
                        customer.picture = file.FileName;
                }
                onlinebookstoreEntities1 db = new onlinebookstoreEntities1();
                db.customers.Add(customer);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
            }

            return View(customer);
        }


and my view is 


@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name)
        </div>
        <div class="txtreg">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.first_name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.last_name)
        </div>
        <div class="txtreg">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.last_name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user_id)
        </div>
        <div class="txtreg">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user_id)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password)
        </div>
        <div class="txtreg">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address)
        </div>
        <div class="txtreg">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.city)
        </div>
        <div class="txtreg">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.city)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.state)
        </div>
        <div class="txtreg">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.state)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.zip)
        </div>
        <div class="txtreg">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.zip)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.country)
        </div>
        <div class="txtreg">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.country)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email)
        </div>
        <div class="txtreg">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.phone)
        </div>
        <div class="txtreg">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.phone)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.picture)
        </div>
        <div class="btnreg">
           <input type="file" id="picture" value="Upload Picture" />
        </div>


        <div class="txtreg">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.rememberme)   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.rememberme)
        </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Create Account" name="btnsub" />

}
```

Comment: i m not getting ur question????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save a picture in the database your property have to look like this:

```
    [DisplayName("Billede")]
    [MaxLength]
    public byte[] PhotoFile { get; set; }
```

and not:

```
       [Display(Name = "Picture")]
    public string picture { get; set; }
```

You save your picture like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Photo", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhotoFile)
                <input type="file" name="Image" />
```

And the ActionResult method inside your PhotoController would be

```
    public ActionResult Create(Photo photo, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
```

and the actual saving of the photo itself

```
   if (image != null)
            {
                photo.ImageFileName = image.FileName;
                photo.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
                photo.PhotoFile = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                image.InputStream.Read(photo.PhotoFile, 0, image.ContentLength);
            }
            context.Add<Photo>(photo);
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Hope you can connect the dots.

Mohammad

Comment: Thanks dear i have done this but not this way as you told because in this way picture will stored in database and i want to save picture in folder not database, & complete path in database.

Comment: @user3804714 Mohammad, will you have this form `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Photo", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))` inside your `Registration form`?

Answer (score 0):

check your **image** folder permissions, If not, set it to all read, write, execute permissions. Try to debug the code and check whether the file is null or any exception fires while **file.SaveAs** called

Answer (score 0):

Saving url into db is quite simple.At the same time you can save the picture in byte format in db.In your customer model you have

Method-1:
Change **string** type or any other type to **byte**.
 So In this picture if you want to save the picture you convert picture to byte type instead of string in your customer table in db.

```
//before
     [Display(Name = "Picture")]
        public string picture { get; set; }
    //After changing in db you add the table  in entity framework .edmx  and now it becomes
     [Display(Name = "Picture")]
        public byte[] picture { get; set; }
```

Here follows your code to save picture in byte format in db.

In your controller

```
public ActionResult Register(customer model)
{
                        string ImageName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + ImageName);
                        file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
                        customer newRecord = new customer ();
                        newRecord.username= customer.username;
                        \\Assign for remaining feilds in table in this way.

                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                            byte[] picArray = ms.GetBuffer();
                            newRecord.picture= picArray ;
                        }
            onlinebookstoreEntities1 db = new onlinebookstoreEntities1();
            db.customers.Add(newRecord);
            db.SaveChanges();

            }
```

In your Register View

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ConfigAssetData", "Home", new { @tabno = "3" },      FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
                    {



<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name)
</div>
<div class="txtreg">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.first_name)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.last_name)
</div>
<div class="txtreg">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.last_name)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user_id)
</div>
<div class="txtreg">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user_id)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password)
</div>
<div class="txtreg">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address)
</div>
<div class="txtreg">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.city)
</div>
<div class="txtreg">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.city)
</div>
  @*UploadFile*@
**<input type="file" class="file-input" name="file"/>**

 @*Similar code here...*@

 }
 </div>
```

Method-2:
Especially in your case as you need to save picture path what you all need to do is:-
In your Controller

```
 public ActionResult Register(customer model)
{
                        string ImageName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + ImageName);
                        file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
                        customer newRecord = new customer ();
                        newRecord.username= customer.username;
                        //.......saving picture url......
                        newRecord.picture = physicalPath;
                        //Assign for remaining feilds in table in this way.

            onlinebookstoreEntities1 db = new onlinebookstoreEntities1();
            db.customers.Add(newRecord);
            db.SaveChanges();

             }
```

*If you right click on your images folder and click "Open folder in windows explorer" you can see your pic uploaded.*

Comment: Saving images in database is expensive than saving them in the folder